# Xcode 4 stopped giving stack traces, what happened?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging

Xcode 4 used to give me nice stack traces when it crashed in my log, how it just gives a bunch of reference numbers that mean nothing to me:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' [__NSCFNumber URLEncodedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x91e5330' *** First throw call stack: (0x1d22052 0x364ed0a 0x1d23ced 0x1c88f00 0x1c88ce2 0xb9935 0xb999f 0xb6179 0xf1c8c 0x8278b 0xe4be4 0xd3f64e 0xd3f941 0xd5147d 0xd5166f 0xd5193b 0xd523df 0xd52986 0xd525a4 0xd5b35 0xd0971d 0xd09952 0x94286d 0x1cf6966 0x1cf6407 0x1c597c0 0x1c58db4 0x1c58ccb 0x4307879 0x430793e 0xc79a9b 0x2b83 0x2a45) terminate called throwing an exception
```

What happened and how do I get it back to nice pretty stack traces with object references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'bunch of reference numbers' *is* the stack trace. What you are used to see are the symbols that map to those addresses. My guess is that for some reason gdb cannot map the addresses to symbol names.

Maybe you inadvertently changed your compiler/linker settings and the debugging information is not generated anymore, so the only thing that can be shown is the addresses.

Try creating a brand new application, and write code that crashes on purpose to see if you get the stack trace there. If you do, then comparing the settings between the two projects should point you to the problem.

Good luck.